# LeetCode Count number of set bits solution

Tags: c++, bitwise

Question - Write a function that takes an unsigned integer and return the number of '1' bits it has (also known as the Hamming weight).

```
int hammingWeight(uint32_t n) {
        int count = 0;
        while(n>0){
            count+=n&1;
            n>>=1;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Can you come up with a better method?

One gentleman came up with this

```
int hammingWeight(uint32_t n) {
    int count = 0;

    while (n) {
        n &= (n - 1);
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

How does one come up with such creative solutions?

And do you have a better one or any improvements I can make to my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Because of the way Code Review works, only *your* code can be reviewed.  Therefore, I will not say anything on the code written by "one gentleman".)

The first thing I see is: *use consistent indentation and add spaces.*  Your code becomes much more readable if you format it like this:

```
int hammingWeight(uint32_t n) {
    int count = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        count += n & 1;
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return count;
}
```

Also, it is probably a good idea to use `std::uint32_t` instead of `uint32_t` in C++.

You can make this function `constexpr` and `noexcept`.  Simple computations like this can be done at compile time, and benefit from inlining.

This function can also be generalized to take any unsigned integer type.  A template version may look like:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T> && std::is_unsigned_v<T>>>
constexpr int hammingWeight(T n) noexcept
{
    // the implementation is the same
}
```

The implementation is good enough and very readable IMO.  You don't have to get very creative unless measuring reveals the necessity of optimization.

In C++20, we have a standard function for this — `std::popcount`, in header `<bit>`.